# Symfony2 - Removing the AcmeBundle demo results in a security provider error

Tags: php, symfony

I have downloaded and installed the Symfony2 standard edition.  I've done all the steps detailed in the [github readme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/README.md) to remove the AcmeBundle that serves as a demo to the framework.  When attempting to access the console to double check my routes:

```
$ php app/console router:debug
```

I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
The child node "providers" at path "security" must be configured.
```

When I undelete security.providers in my `security.yml` file, so I'm left with:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user: { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

I get a different but similar error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                          
You must at least add one authentication provider.
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix it.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need the provides, like this config:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            security: false

        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

Comment: +1 but you shouldn't really have to define a provider if you don't have one. I guess the reason the security bundle requires this is because if you don't need security, you don't need the bundle.

Comment: The docs should really be updated to reflect this.  Your answer is a far cry different than simply deleting/removing those entries outright.

Comment: +1 for headache-generating inconsistent/out-of-date documentation.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the minimal file I could obtain that works without exceptions is:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        anonymous:
            anonymous: ~

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
```

<sub>Symfony 2.3.3.</sub>

Comment: this works for 2.4.1 too. so does commenting out the import in config.yml